# set chromium tab option to enable "mute" by command line

Tags: linux, command-line, google-chrome, chromium

Chromium has cool options. For example, I enjoy the "mute" tab feature. This can be enabled graphically by go to chrome://flags and then enable "Enable tab audio muting UI control".

However, how can above be achieved through command line? Where are Chromium options stored and how can one manipulate in this case?

I am also interested in setting other Chromium options on command line, but most specially this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Windows:**

```
# Change the path to match your Chrome or Chromium Installation
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-tab-audio-muting
```

**Mac:**

```
# Chromium
# Change the path to match your Chrome or Chromium Installation
/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium --enable-tab-audio-muting`

# Google Chrome (with escaped spaces)
# Change the path to match your Chrome or Chromium Installation
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-tab-audio-muting
```

**Linux:**

```
# Chromium
chromium-browser --enable-tab-audio-muting

# Google Chrome
google-chrome --enable-tab-audio-muting
```

These require all other windows to be closed.

[Source](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)

[Switches that can be manipulated via command line](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: my apology for not saying linux tag. Actually I would like to save the setting in my user preferences. But this is closest answer possibly. Kind regards.